# node js ffmpeg hls stream sound is repeating and overlays to each other

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm trying to stream video and audio with rtmp and I'm stack with problem that I hear sound which overlays to each other and always repeating. But my target is to not repeating and overlay audio to each other. Parsing hls performs with `hls.js`

This is my ffmpeg config which creates 4 streaming files which includes in master file `index.m3u8`

```
let argv = ['-y', '-i', inPath];
  Array.prototype.push.apply(argv, [
    '-filter_complex', '[0:v]split=4[v1][v2][v3][v4];[v1]copy[v1out];[v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out];[v3]scale=w=800:h=480[v3out];[v4]scale=w=640:h=360[v4out]',
    '-map', '[v1out]', '-c:v:0', 'libx264', '-x264-params', 'nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1', '-b:v:0', '5M', '-maxrate:v:0', '5M', '-bufsize:v:0', '5M', '-preset', 'veryfast', '-g', '48', '-sc_threshold', '0', '-keyint_min', '48',
    '-map', '[v2out]', '-c:v:1', 'libx264', '-x264-params', 'nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1', '-b:v:1', '3M', '-maxrate:v:1', '3M', '-bufsize:v:1', '3M', '-preset', 'veryfast', '-g', '48', '-sc_threshold', '0', '-keyint_min', '48',
    '-map', '[v3out]', '-c:v:2', 'libx264', '-x264-params', 'nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1', '-b:v:2', '1M', '-maxrate:v:2', '1M', '-bufsize:v:2', '1M', '-preset', 'veryfast', '-g', '48', '-sc_threshold', '0', '-keyint_min', '48',
    '-map', '[v4out]', '-c:v:3', 'libx264', '-x264-params', 'nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1', '-b:v:3', '600k', '-maxrate:v:3', '600k', '-bufsize:v:3', '600k', '-preset', 'veryfast', '-g', '48', '-sc_threshold', '0', '-keyint_min', '48',
    '-map', 'a:0', '-c:a:0', 'aac', '-b:a:0', '96k', '-ac', '2',
    '-map', 'a:0', '-c:a:1', 'aac', '-b:a:1', '96k', '-ac', '2',
    '-map', 'a:0', '-c:a:2', 'aac', '-b:a:2', '96k', '-ac', '2',
    '-map', 'a:0', '-c:a:3', 'aac', '-b:a:3', '96k', '-ac', '2',
    '-f', 'hls', '-hls_time', '2', '-hls_flags', 'independent_segments', '-hls_list_size', '2', '-hls_segment_type', 'mpegts', '-hls_segment_filename', `${ouPath}/%v_data%02d.ts`, '-master_pl_name', `index.m3u8`,
    '-var_stream_map', 'v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3', `${ouPath}/stream_%v.m3u8`
  ]);
  this.ffmpeg_exec = spawn(this.conf.ffmpeg, argv)
```

index.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-STREAM- 
INF:BANDWIDTH=5605600,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.64002a,mp4a.40.2"
stream_0.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM- 
INF:BANDWIDTH=3405600,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.640020,mp4a.40.2"
stream_1.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1205600,RESOLUTION=800x480,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
stream_2.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=765600,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
stream_3.m3u8
```

Below is streaming files from index.m3u8 with dynamic chunks

stream_0.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:2.400000,
0_data00.ts
```

stream_1.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:87
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:1.600000,
1_data87.ts
#EXTINF:2.400000,
1_data88.ts
```

stream_2.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:110
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:2.400000,
2_data110.ts
#EXTINF:1.600000,
2_data111.ts
```

stream_3.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:128
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:2.400000,
3_data128.ts
#EXTINF:1.600000,
3_data129.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. OBS Studio record sound from screen and thats why I heard repeated sound